# Implement Rails Helpers Effectively Taking Multiple Blocks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6.1

So I'd love to be able to write a Rails helper that either takes chunks of of the view as arguments (pretty sure this isn't possible) or changes how helpers inside a chunk operate.  Ideally (but I'm pretty sure it's impossible), I could do something like the following where top_context_builder then executes with proc/block arguments corresponding to both firstcontent and secondcontent (e.g. maybe I want to interleave them in output as firstcontent secondcontent secondcontent firstcontent)

```
<%= top_context builder: foo_builder, argone:  %>
   firstcontent
<% argtwo: %>
   secondcontent
<% end %>
```

But what seems more plausible is that maybe I could inject context into the block I'm executing.  So is there any way that top_context could provide the argument to builder to the helpers get_first_context and get_second_context and then somehow get_first_context stores it's block argument in some location setup by top_context so then get_second_context could have access to the builder arg, a proc/block for firstcontent and a proc/block for secondcontent?

```
<%= top_context builder: foo_builder do %>
   <%= get_first_context do %>
      firstcontent
   <% end %>
   <%= get_second_context do %>
      secondcontent
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The question is how I could get the builder arg and firstcontent to get_second_context without polluting globals (e.g so I could use it in a nested fashion).  I'm probably being dumb but would appreciate any thoughts.

(Yes, I think I could use content_for and save these things to identifiers but if I wanted to use the helper in a nested fashion it seems like that would lead to name collisions).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is simply block arguments. When using `yield` you can yield any number of arguments to the block:

```
def foo(&block)
  yield "Hello", "World"
end

foo { |*args| puts args.join(" ") }
```

This is how Rails does both `form_for/form_with` as well as `fields_for`. The methods simply yield a form builder instance that you're calling methods on instead of monkeying around with the rendering context.

```
<%= form_with(model: @book) do |form| %>
  <%= form.fields_for(:author) do |author| %>
     <%= author.label :name %>
     <%= author.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

So in your example it would look like:

```
<%= top_context builder: foo_builder do |ctx| %>
   <%= ctx.get_first_context do |local_ctx| %>
      <%= local_ctx.firstcontent %>
   <% end %>
   <%= ctx.get_second_context do |local_ctx| %>
      <%= local_ctx.secondcontent %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This does require a bit of refactoring from a simple helper method but if you need this kind of complexity a separate object is already warranted.

Comment: Yes but the top_context builder needs to get both of the arguments so it can, eg, interleave copies of firs and second content.